# Link to reset password doesn't work after localization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, localization

I created a link to reset passwords according to Michael Hartl's tutorial https://www.railstutorial.org/book/password_reset 
It was working fine up to the moment in which I started using different languages (localization) in my app.

Instead of getting into my mailbox an e-mail with a link like: http://my-page.com/password_resets/3BdBrXeQZSWqFIDRN8cxHA/edit?email=michael%40michaelhartl.com
I get an error for a code: edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_token, email: @user.email), which is:

ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"password_resets", :email=>"michael@michaelhartl.com", :id=>nil, :locale=>"Ti1LJmD4AcBwN3TNUENnBw"} missing required keys: [:id]):

Because, I guess, the part which was an "id", now is "locale". And I don't know how to skip it, to create: either the same link like before or the link which would additionally consider I18n.locale (that would be perfect). And it seems to be like it has to be solved at the level of the link (not e.g. routes.rb, because the rest of the app works fine in 3 languages).

Does anyone has an idea how this link should be created?

Comment: Could you please expand on what 'started using localization' means? I'm trying to think of how http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html comes into play here.

Comment: Actually this is my page: http://fantasytopfootball.com/ - you will see 3 languages which work fine but after 3 months I realized that Password Reset raises an error described above. Because then a page changed e.g. from http://fantasytopfootball.com/login to http://fantasytopfootball.com/en/login

Comment: Ah ha! There's the implementation detail. The language is in the URL...

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading this: https://phraseapp.com/blog/posts/rails-i18n-setting-and-managing-locales/

And it looks like you are looking for Route Scopes:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

Basically, you've added the locale in the place where Rails automagically expects the ID to be. So you need to add some code telling your application 'Hey buddy, this first argument is the locale, not the ID!'

Think of how you can hit `/posts/1` and `/posts/new` and Rails knows '1' is an ID, and 'new' is not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I decided that I will create this link manually. I'm not a fan of this kind of solutions but... it (finally!) works: <%= link_to("Reset", "mypage.com" + "/" + "password_resets" + "/" + @user.reset_token + "/" + "edit" + "?" + "email" + "=" + @user.email) %>

Comment: Cool. Just remember that once you start kludging, you might not be able to stop. This is going to be a problem elsewhere, you may not have noticed it yet :P